# Trouble targetting framework in managed C++ project with VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, managed-c++

I'm trying to get all my projects converted and working under VS 2012. I'm still having issues with a managed C++ project that I need to keep on the 2.0 framework.

I was able to edit the vcxproj file and set the target framework version to v2.0. Once I did that, the warning icon in the projects that had references to it went away. In the Framework and References property window for this project it even says Targeted framework: .NETFramework,Version=v2.0.

The problem is that the projects referencing it still can't resolve the namespace and it gives the error regarding missing assembly reference. When I look at the properties of the reference library, I see that for Runtime Version it still says v4.0.30319.

So something is missing to get this managed C++ project to truely target v2.0. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it is the same for 2012 but for 2010 also needed to have 2008 installed in order to build 3.5 and earlier.  Need to change the platform toolset to v90

Comment: Thank you! Setting the platform to v90 resolved my issue. Thankfully I still had VS 2008 installed as well. Think I might push to try and get away from 2.0 since I really don't want to install VS 2008 on the new computer.